# Do we need to add new version to core data if we add new tables into it?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an existing core data project now I want to add some more tables into it so my question is do we need to add change current version of CoreData and add new version to it ? Also my app is already live. Now I want to publish another version of application by adding some more tables to it.

Comment: Would be nice to vote the first answer :-) Thx

Comment: Oh I am sorry for late I am doing it now, Thanks for my help Popeinvestor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration

Core Data Migration
In order to follow core data migration we should keep on versioning our .xcdatamodeld file. Also to address new changes we should not make any changes in existing data model. Instead we should create a new version of .xcdatamodeld and perform changes there. We should follow core data migration if there are changes in:

Entity -
Add a entity,
Remove a entity,
Renaming a entity.
Attribute-
Add an attribute,
Remove an attribute,
Renaming an attribute,
Relationship -
Add a relationship ,
Remove an relationship ,
Renaming an relationship .

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make an explicit migration, especially if you have your app live and there is user data in the field.

Core Data has a method for it, the
[Lightweight Migration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration). Core Data can typically perform an automatic data migration, referred to as lightweight migration. Lightweight migration infers the migration from the differences between the source and the destination managed object models.

If you want to adapt also parts of your old model, when they are affected by your changes you may use the [Heavyweight Migration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/heavyweight_migration)

There you may migrate the old user data and you can change your old model if it is affected by your changes and your changes are logically complex.

Nevertheless if there are no changes which affect your old model you may also only add a table, but I personally migrate.....